# Fancybox 2 - Thumbnail Title

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I would like to be able to have a title displayed over each thumbnail. Is this possible? Been trying to find it in the documentation, and through custom attempts for a while but haven't gotten anywhere. Similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690765/fabcybox-1-3-4-thumbnail-title-on-hover) though it wasn't answered.

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14186766/1055987?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same, for me the best solution was to put everything inside a  element and use `<figcaption>` for the title below the thumb image. This is an example:

```
<li>
  <figure><a class="fancybox" id="gen_acc2" href="images/prodsec/prodsec_gtv100_pt.jpg" 
     data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
  <img src="images/prod_thumbs/prod_img_gtv100.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  <figcaption><h4>GTV 100</h4></figcaption></figure>
```

Hope it helps.